# Why is getline written so strangely?

Tags: c++, getline

I don't understand the design decisions behind the C++ getline function.

Why does it take a stream and a string by reference as arguments, only to return the same stream that was passed in? It seems more intuitive to only take the stream as an argument, then return the string that was read. Returning the same stream lets you chain the call, but would anyone really want to use `getline(getline(stream, x), y)`?

Additionally, why is the function not in the `std` namespace like the rest of the standard library?

Comment: Yes, people write `while (getline(stream x)) ...` a lot.

Comment: I agree that `getline(getline(stream, x), y)` is icky. I would prefer to see `getline(stream, x) && getline(stream , y)`.

Answer (score 4):

If the function returned a string, there would be no way of indicating that the read failed, as all string values are valid values that could be returned by this (or any other) function. On the other hand, a stream has lots of error indicator flags that can be tested by the code that calls getline. So people can write code like:

```
 while( std::getline( std::cin, somestring )) {
     // do stuff with somestring
 }
```

and it is hard to see how you could write similar code if `getline` returned a string.

> why is the function not in the std namespace like the rest of the standard library?

It is in the `std` namespace - what makes you think otherwise?

Comment: Probably the fact that it can be called without a `std::` qualifier, thanks to ADL.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas It was because of the lack of `std::` qualifier. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, that would make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> Why does it take a stream and a string by reference as arguments, only to return the same stream that was passed in?

It is a common pattern in the stream library to do that. It means you can test the operation being performed as you perform it. For example:

```
std::string line;
while(std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    // use line here because we know the read succeeded
}
```

You can also make succinct parsers by "chaining" stream functions:

std::string key, value;

```
if(std::getline(std::getline(in, key, '='), value))
    my_map[key] = value;
```

> It seems more intuitive to only take the stream as an argument, then return the string that was read.

The problem with returning a new string every call is that you are constantly allocating new memory for them instead of reusing the memory already allocated to the string you passed in or that it gained while iterating through a loop.

```
// Here line will not need to allocate memory every time
// through the loop. Only when it finds a longer line than
// it has capacity for:

std::string line;
while(std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    // use line here because we know the read succeeded
}
```

Comment: That's a good point. I didn't think of the memory allocation.